# Java and Database significant slowness

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading

I have a java program that creates thread for each field being read from the DB. I have a lot of fields (+10,000). I had problems in significant slowness. In addition to that, the program enters an infinite loop at the end. i.e, there is one or more threads that never ends, which make the loop infinite. I tried to reduce the number of fields that the program reads from inside the Java code, by specifying the number (PK) of the item to read like in the following statement:

```
"select hName from schema.table where 
ID between 1 AND 200";
```

The program works fine after this change. I need to know what should I do to solve such issue. Does statements that contains conditions like, (where) affects the java program performance? If I didn't specify an order or a condition, but I have primary key in my table, does making the statement without any condition a better option ?

There are some other insert statements in other classes. I do synchronize the statements there to avoid having two threads with the same record number.

```
synchronized (this) {
            Query = " insert into schema.table values (default,?,?,?)";
            Stmt = DBConnection.con.Statement(Query);
        }
```

The concerned piece of code in the main function is :

```
try {
    ExecutorService threadExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    while (resultSet.next()) {
        name = resultSet.getString("hName");
        MyRunnable worker = new Myrunnable(name);
        threadExecutor.execute(worker);
        Counter++;
    }

    //This never appears
    System.out.println("End while with counter" + Counter);

    threadExecutor.shutdown();
    System.out.println("thread shutdown"); //this never appears

    // Wait until all threads are finish
    while (!threadExecutor.isTerminated()) {
        threadExecutor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        System.out.println("inside the thread termination loop."); //I have infinite loop

    }

    System.out.println("Finished all threads"); //never appears

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println("END MAIN");

DBConnection.con.close();
```

The class that implements runnable is here:

```
//The constructor
String threadName=null;
MyRunnable (String name)  {
    threadName=name;
}

public void run() {
    myclass Obj=new myclass();
    try {
        Obj.myFunction(name);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Got an Exception: "+e.getMessage());
    }
    System.out.println(" thread exiting" + threadName);
}
```

Comment: Having 10,000+ threads in a Java application can by itself significantly slow things down. Unless you are running on 10,000+ core server.

Comment: But I'm using thread pool. As far as I understand, since I specify the limit in this statement: ExecutorService threadExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
, this is the maximum number of threads at a time, the rest of tasks will stay in a queue.

Comment: That definitely changes the picture. Without any mention of the thread pooling I just assumed that all 10,000+ are created and then destroyed independently.

Answer (score 2):

> Q: I have a java program that creates thread for each field being read
>   from the DB. I have a lot of fields (+10,000)

Danger, Will Robinson!

Did anybody in the design phase suggestion ... that's crazy?  Don't do that :)

> Q: Does statements that contains conditions like, (where) affects the
>   java program performance?

A: Are you asking "does a SQL query with a "where" clause usually perform better than a naive dump of the entire table?"

If so: Yes, "where" clauses have been know to enhance query performance :)

Comment: Why not if I'm using thread pool and specify the pool size as 4 for example, hence, there will be only 4 threads at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Unfettered by additional facts, I can't imagine why you would ever create 10,000 threads for any reason. Context switching would kill you even on a server with dozens of cores. How is your code being executed? In a simple java program running on a PC? On a server? If it is running on a server, you should look into using an application server. Then you take advantage of a couple of things: First, you can get rid of all use of threads and rely on the application server to scale request to logical components (perhaps using EJB3 components--which I would recommend you take a look at). Second, you can take advantage of connection pooling. Creating a connection to a database is an expensive proposition. If you use connections within a pool, the application server will handle managing all of the connections, and only create new connections when needed (see Java EE documentation and your application server documentation to set this up).

Finally, make sure that you have appropriate indexes on your table. For example, I assume that ID has been indexed. Is that the case? Run explain plan, and look at how many rows of the table are being scanned to answer the query (see MySQL docs for an explanation on how to use explain plan functionality).

Comment: For my index, I used AI number. The reason for using multi-threading from the first place was that the function to be executed on every field value may take a lot of time (ex: SSL connection). So, using multi-threading for every connection was the option. From my understanding for threads pool, I'm defining a fixed number of threads, so I'm creating 10000 threads for example, but there is no more than 10 (or any fixed number) of threads can run at the same time.